# Rsync SuSE filesystem without destroying networking

Tags: networking, rsync, sles

I've got a script that pulls down an entire SLES11 OS from a remote machine. These are my include and exclude directories

`--include=/bin 
--include=/etc 
--include=/lib 
--include=/lib64 
--include=/opt 
--include=/sbin 
--include=/usr
--include=/var`

`--exclude=/boot
--exclude=/etc/sysconfig/network 
--exclude=/media 
--exclude=/mnt 
--exclude=/proc 
--exclude=/selinux 
--exclude=/lost+found 
--exclude=/dev
--exclude=/sys 
--exclude=/var/lib/ntp/proc 
--exclude=/var/cache/yum 
{...and some proprietary stuff}`

Problem is, when I reboot my computer, the working nic in the rsynced machine shows up as eth2 instead of eth0 (which throws off everything).

All other rsync problems that I'm probably going to run in to aside and ask about here or at unix.se, what other files should I be avoiding to not have my machine reboot with a new nic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the generated udev rules since the original MACs defined by the source will no longer be the same?

/etc/udev/rules.d contains your original MAC address(s), not rsyncing that directory or clearing out that directory before rebooting will make your troubles go away.

Comment: I don't see anything in /lib/udev that specifically references an ethernet interface or has the original MAC address hard-coded in it.    I was planning on not rsyncing /lib/udev as my next logical step anyway.